# Time out problem while installing wireshark

Tags: software-installation

I am getting following error message when I am trying to install **wireshark** using:

```
sudo apt-get install wireshark
```

output:

```
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/universe libsmi2ldbl amd64 0.4.8+dfsg2-4
  Could not connect to 10.1.101.150:3128 (10.1.101.150), connection timed out
```

Please help me to come out of this problem...

Comment: It seems you are using a local proxy. Is it working?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like apt is trying to connect to a local server on your network to retrieve the file. Are you running a local cache server? Is your IT department doing so? Perhaps you should contact your local administrator to get the cache updated.